# How do you set up use HttpOnly cookies in PHP

Tags: php, security, cookies, xss, httponly

How can I set the cookies in my `PHP apps` as `HttpOnly cookies`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/528405/which-browsers-do-support-httponly-cookies Has the browser support info.

Comment: @Tchalvak No, the current answers are still authoritative. Nothing has changed since 2008 regarding HTTP-only cookie setting in PHP. _Which browsers support HTTP-only cookies_ is a different question, with a different answer.

Comment: You may use `$cookie->setHttpOnly(true);` with https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Cookie

Answer (score 105, accepted):

- For **your cookies**, see this answer.
- For **PHP's own session cookie** (`PHPSESSID`, by default), see [@richie's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8726269/1820)

The [`setcookie()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) and [`setrawcookie()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setrawcookie.php) functions, introduced the boolean `httponly` parameter, back in the dark ages of PHP 5.2.0, making this nice and easy. Simply set the 7th parameter to true, as per the syntax

*Function syntax simplified for brevity*

```
setcookie(    $name, $value, $expire, $path, $domain, $secure, $httponly )
setrawcookie( $name, $value, $expire, $path, $domain, $secure, $httponly )
```

In PHP < 8, specify `NULL` for parameters you wish to remain as default.

In PHP >= 8 you can benefit from using named parameters. See [this question about named params](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64997399/1820).

```
setcookie( $name, $value, httponly:true )
```

It is also possible using the older, lower-level [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function:

```
header( "Set-Cookie: name=value; HttpOnly" );
```

You may also want to consider if you should be setting the `Secure` parameter.

Comment: With PHP 8's named parameters, we'll finally be able to make the `set_cookie` call less verbose if we don't need to set the other parameters. For example `set_cookie($name, $value, httponly: true)`.

Comment: on PHP 7.3.0, we can use array.

`setcookie("name", "value", ['httponly' => true]);`

Answer (score 132):

For PHP's own session cookies on Apache:
add this to your Apache configuration or `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule php5_module>
    php_flag session.cookie_httponly on
</IfModule>
```

This can also be set within a script, as long as it is called before `session_start()`.

```
ini_set( 'session.cookie_httponly', 1 );
```

Comment: +1 as this is a good thing (for security) to have in place on your entire server but instead added to the `php.ini`.

Comment: Please note php_flag should be used instead: "Don't use php_value to set boolean values. php_flag should be used instead." http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php

Comment: @OndrejMachulda Changing `php_value` to `php_flag` doesn't work. I just tried it on my server..

Comment: @Nate: When changing to `php_flag`, you must change also the value - to either `on` or `off` - see the manual.

Answer (score 15):

Note that PHP session cookies don't use `httponly` by default.

To do that:

```
$sess_name = session_name();
if (session_start()) {
    setcookie($sess_name, session_id(), null, '/', null, null, true);
}
```

A couple of items of note here:

- You have to call `session_name()`
  before `session_start()`
- This also
  sets the default path to '/', which
  is necessary for Opera but which PHP
  session cookies don't do by default
  either.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php It can be done automatically via the above PHP function instead of custom coding.

Answer (score 12):

Be aware that HttpOnly doesn't stop cross-site scripting; instead, it neutralizes one possible attack, and currently does that only on IE (FireFox exposes HttpOnly cookies in XmlHttpRequest, and Safari doesn't honor it at all). By all means, turn HttpOnly on, but don't drop even an hour of output filtering and fuzz testing in trade for it.

Comment: This situation may have changed since '08, now.
Here is a more current/updated list: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/528405/which-browsers-do-support-httponly-cookies

Answer (score 8):

```
<?php
//None HttpOnly cookie:
setcookie("abc", "test", NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE); 

//HttpOnly cookie:
setcookie("abc", "test", NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, TRUE); 

?>
```

[Source](http://ilia.ws/archives/121-httpOnly-cookie-flag-support-in-PHP-5.2.html)

Answer (score 5):

You can specify it in the set cookie function [see the php manual](http://uk.php.net/setcookie)

```
setcookie('Foo','Bar',0,'/', 'www.sample.com'  , FALSE, TRUE);
```

Answer (score 4):

Explanation here from Ilia... 5.2 only though

[httpOnly cookie flag support in PHP 5.2](http://ilia.ws/archives/121-httpOnly-cookie-flag-support-in-PHP-5.2.html)

As stated in that article, you can set the header yourself in previous versions of PHP

```
header("Set-Cookie: hidden=value; httpOnly");
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use this in a header file.

```
// setup session enviroment
ini_set('session.cookie_httponly',1);
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies',1);
```

This way all future session cookies will use httponly.

- Updated.

Comment: Just FYI session.use_only_cookies is on by default in PHP >5.3

Comment: and correct is "all future **session** cookies" will use httponly, not custom ones ...

Answer (score 2):

The right syntax of the php_flag command is

```
php_flag  session.cookie_httponly On
```

And be aware, just first answer from server set the cookie and here (for example You can see the "HttpOnly" directive. So for testing delete cookies from browser after every testing request.

Answer (score 1):

A more elegant solution since **PHP >=7.0**

```
session_start(['cookie_lifetime' => 43200,'cookie_secure' => true,'cookie_httponly' => true]);
```

[session_start](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

[session_start options](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-strict-mode)

Answer (score 0):

Solução `session_start(['cookie_lifetime' => 43200,'cookie_secure' => true,'cookie_httponly' => true]);`

Dessa forma funcionou para mim na última versão do chromedriver.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).