# Which browsers do support HttpOnly cookies?

Tags: security, browser, cookies, xss, httponly

Which browsers do support HttpOnly cookies, and since which version?

Please see http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001167.html for a discussion of HttpOnly cookies and XSS-prevention.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Feel free to add to this list:

- Internet Explorer since 6 sp1 ([source](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/644.cfm), [source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533046.aspx))
- Firefox since 2.0.0.5 ([source](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/644.cfm))
- Opera since 9.5 (possibly earlier) ([source](http://manicode.blogspot.com/2008/06/opera-95-httponly-read-prevention.html))
- Safari since 4 ([source](http://www.greebo.net/2009/06/09/httponly-in-safari-40-release/))
- Chrome since 1.0.154 ([source](http://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel/release-notes/releasenotes1015453))

Comment: Thanks! Found this list which adds some info: http://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTTPOnly#Browsers_Supporting_HTTPOnly

Comment: @knorv : Link is case sensitive and/or has been modified: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly#Browsers_Supporting_HttpOnly

Comment: Link for Chrome is dead (**Page not found**
We're sorry, but we were unable to locate the page you requested.).

Comment: somebody should update this list again or is it obsolete now with https??

Answer (score -10):

All major browsers support HttpOnly.

- Microsoft IE 5.0+
- Mozilla Firefox 1.0+
- Google Chrome
- Apple Safari
- Opera 8.0+

Comment: I don't think that's true--can you provide references?

Comment: I've seen reports that "IE6 SP1" and "Firefox 2.0.0.5" "now support HttpOnly cookies", which leads me to believe that at least IE5 and Firefox 1 *dont* support it.