# Login 'Remember me' Cookie - Best security practices

Tags: php, security, cookies, authentication

I am looking for an up to date method of keeping a user logged in with the famous 'Remember me' checkbox.

This is what I have got so far from combining other posts and tutorials:

- User enters username and password. If valid - A Cookie is generated containing an **Identifier** and a **Token**. Both of these values are unguessable random numbers/characters.
- The **Identifier** and **Token** are stored in a database with the **user id**.
- When a non-logged-in user visits the website with a login Cookie, the **Identifier** is looked up in the database; if present, the **Token** is compared; if not, the Cookie is ignored and the user must login with his/her password.
- If the **Tokens** match - the user is authenticated:

  - The Cookie is destroyed.
  - A new Cookie is issued with a different **Identifier** and **Token**.
  - The Database is **updated** with the new **Identifier** and **Token** values against the **user id**.

Have I missed anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the mechanisms down in order for you to store the cookies based on user login status to the db. I would still do a checklist to be completely sure that it's secured:

**Limit the amount of sensitive information stored in the cookie.**

```
** this is ok, you're only storing Identifier and Token information
```

**`Limit the subdomains and paths to prevent interception by another application.`**

**Enforce SSL so the cookie isn’t sent in cleartext.**

```
** if you don't already have ssl, which is a good idea to have, you can enable ssl to send that information encrypted (you have to do that in your web server config). you can issue yourself (self-signed) ssl certificate, it won't be insured but at least the information would go in or transfer as encrypted.
```

**Make the cookie HttpOnly so its not accessible to javascript.**

You can implement is by looking at a previous stackoverflow post:    [How do you set up use HttpOnly cookies in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36877/how-do-you-set-up-use-httponly-cookies-in-php)