# How to set the 'secure' and the 'httpOnly' attribute for any session cookie from DOCKERFILE

Tags: docker, session, kubernetes, dockerfile, alpine-linux

I'm using this dockerfile image https://github.com/ulsmith/alpine-apache-php7 for my project and I want to set the 'secure' and the 'httpOnly' attribute to true.

My main goal is to have them as default values for all cookies and sessions on the server.

I added the ENV variables corresponding to that :

```
ENV PHP_SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE=On
ENV PHP_SESSION_COOKIE_PATH=/
ENV PHP_SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY=On
```

Also I tried :

```
ENV PHP_SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE=true
ENV PHP_SESSION_COOKIE_PATH=/
ENV PHP_SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY=true
```

And still, I see them set as false when I browse the website.

[image]

Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:edge
MAINTAINER Paul Smith <pa.ulsmith.net>

# Add repos
RUN echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing" >> /etc/apk/repositories

# Add basics first
RUN apk update && apk upgrade && apk add \
    bash apache2 php7-apache2 curl ca-certificates openssl openssh git php7 php7-phar php7-json php7-iconv php7-openssl tzdata openntpd nano

# Add Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php && mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

# Setup apache and php
RUN apk add \
    php7-ftp \
    php7-xdebug \
    php7-mcrypt \
    php7-mbstring \
    php7-soap \
    php7-gmp \
    php7-pdo_odbc \
    php7-dom \
    php7-pdo \
    php7-zip \
    php7-mysqli \
    php7-sqlite3 \
    php7-pdo_pgsql \
    php7-bcmath \
    php7-gd \
    php7-odbc \
    php7-pdo_mysql \
    php7-pdo_sqlite \
    php7-gettext \
    php7-xml \
    php7-xmlreader \
    php7-xmlwriter \
    php7-tokenizer \
    php7-xmlrpc \
    php7-bz2 \
    php7-pdo_dblib \
    php7-curl \
    php7-ctype \
    php7-session \
    php7-redis \
    php7-exif \
    php7-intl \
    php7-fileinfo \
    php7-ldap \
    php7-apcu

# Problems installing in above stack
RUN apk add php7-simplexml

RUN cp /usr/bin/php7 /usr/bin/php \
    && rm -f /var/cache/apk/*

# Add apache to run and configure
RUN sed -i "s/#LoadModule\ rewrite_module/LoadModule\ rewrite_module/" /etc/apache2/httpd.conf \
    && sed -i "s/#LoadModule\ session_module/LoadModule\ session_module/" /etc/apache2/httpd.conf \
    && sed -i "s/#LoadModule\ session_cookie_module/LoadModule\ session_cookie_module/" /etc/apache2/httpd.conf \
    && sed -i "s/#LoadModule\ session_crypto_module/LoadModule\ session_crypto_module/" /etc/apache2/httpd.conf \
    && sed -i "s/#LoadModule\ deflate_module/LoadModule\ deflate_module/" /etc/apache2/httpd.conf \
    && sed -i "s#^DocumentRoot \".*#DocumentRoot \"/app/public\"#g" /etc/apache2/httpd.conf \
    && sed -i "s#/var/www/localhost/htdocs#/app/public#" /etc/apache2/httpd.conf \
    && printf "\n<Directory \"/app/public\">\n\tAllowOverride All\n</Directory>\n" >> /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
ENV PHP_ALLOW_URL_INCLUDE=On
ENV PHP_SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE=true
ENV PHP_SESSION_COOKIE_PATH=/
ENV PHP_SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY=true
RUN mkdir /app && mkdir /app/public && chown -R apache:apache /app && chmod -R 755 /app && mkdir bootstrap
COPY app/ /app/public/
USER root
RUN chmod 0777 /app/public/api/emiratespost/awbpdf/
RUN chmod 0777 /app/public/assets/media/companies/
RUN chmod 0777 /app/public/assets/media/licenses/
RUN chmod 0777 /app/public/assets/media/payments/
RUN chmod 0777 /app/public/assets/media/products/
RUN chmod 0777 /app/public/assets/media/shipments/
ADD start.sh /bootstrap/
RUN chmod +x /bootstrap/start.sh

EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["/bootstrap/start.sh"]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you set up use HttpOnly cookies in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36877/how-do-you-set-up-use-httponly-cookies-in-php)

Comment: Yes, this will help, but I wanted to enable them from the config file by default.

Comment: This is a specific implementation to this container. Your best bet is to ask the maintainer of the repository or create an issue in their GitHub tracker.

Comment: already did and no reply at all, thanks anw.